# Why do sed a and sed s commands behave differently with respect to escape characters under single quotes and double quotes?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed

I know there are differences between single quotes and double quotes in a `sed` expression, but I didn't know there are differences between `sed a` and `sed s` expressions.

For `sed s` expressions, `\t` is translated as a tab correctly both in single and double quotes. `\\t` also does the same thing in double quotes.

```bash
# '\t' works for single quotes
$ echo -e "abc\n123" | sed 's|abc|&\n\tdef|'
abc
    def
123

# '\\t' fails for single quotes
$ echo -e "abc\n123" | sed 's|abc|&\\n\\tdef|'
abc\n\tdef
123

# '\t' works for double quotes
$ echo -e "abc\n123" | sed "s|abc|&\n\tdef|"
abc
    def
123

# '\\t' also works for double quotes
$ echo -e "abc\n123" | sed "s|abc|&\\n\\tdef|"
abc
    def
123
```

However, in `sed a` expressions, I have to use `\\t` in a single quotes expression and `\\\t` in one with double quotes.

```bash
# '\t' fails for single quotes
$ echo -e "abc\n123" | sed '/abc/a\tdef'
abc
tdef
123

# '\\t' works for single quotes
$ echo -e "abc\n123" | sed '/abc/a\\tdef'
abc
    def
123

# '\t' fails for double quotes
$ echo -e "abc\n123" | sed "/abc/a\tdef"
abc
tdef
123

# '\\t' fails for double quotes
$ echo -e "abc\n123" | sed "/abc/a\\tdef"
abc
tdef
123

# '\\\t' works for double quotes
$ echo -e "abc\n123" | sed "/abc/a\\\tdef"
abc
    def
123
```

I had to change my `sed a` expressions to `sed s` ones to unify the outputs due to this phenomenon. Things work perfectly, but I'd like an explanation.

The commands above are executed on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: To prevent unwanted side-effects use single quotes for all sed commands and if you want a single quote, pop out to the shell `'\''` same goes for shell variables `'"${var}"'`

Comment: Whether `\t` is recognized as a tab depends on what version of `sed` you are using. At the shell prompt, you can enter a literal tab with `Control-V tab`. That should work in Vim and Emacs as well; other editors should have their own ways to enter a literal tab.

Comment: Actually in Emacs out of the box it's C-q tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` has no idea which quotes you use. The shell parses and removes the quotes. Inside single quotes, text is preserved completely verbatim; inside double quotes, the shell performs variable substitution, command substitution, and backslash processing. The rules are simple, but sometimes surprising: in brief, a backslash quotes the next character as literal, and so, a pair of backslashes gets translated to a single backslash. However, backslashes in front of characters which do not need escaping are preserved. So for example, `\t` is equivalent to `\\t` inside double quotes.

`sed` for its part performs another round of backslash processing. In some contexts, some versions of `sed` understand `\t` to represent a literal tab character, but generally not in the text after the `a`, `c`, or `i` commands.

The actual question here is probably actually about the formatting of the `a` command. This differs between `sed` versions, but out of the box on Ubuntu, it simply outputs the literal text after the command. A backslash in this context is just a literal backslash, which again escapes the next character to ensure it is interpreted literally. Unlike the shell, `sed` simply removes this backslash.

In Bash, you can use `$'...'` "C-style" strings which let you encode a literal tab symbolically. However, you need to add literal backslashes in a couple of places: `sed` doesn't accept an unescaped literal newline in the `s` command, and the tab after `a` needs a backslash in order for it not to be skipped as insignificant whitespace.

```
printf '%s\n' abc 123 ghi |
sed -e $'s/abc/&\\\n\tdef/' \
    -e $'/ghi/a\\\tjkl'
```

To reiterate, inside `$'...'` a `\t` gets replaced by the shell with a literal tab character, `\n` with a newline, etc, before the string gets passed on to the command (`sed` in this case).

In the grand scheme of things, you may be better off using a less haphazard tool than `sed` for this. Awk is much easier to read, write, and debug.